# getJson Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: json, jsonp, getjson, same-origin-policy

I just learned that using getJson with a url from another domain/port will usually lead to cross domain policy problem.

With this code:

```
    var appGetApi = "http://localhost:30028/api/values";
    $.getJSON(appGetApi, function (_returnedJson) {
       ...
    });
```

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:30028/api/values. 
Origin http://localhost:17437 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

After searching the web for answers, it seems that adding ***&callback=?*** is a famous fix. So i did that.

```
    var appGetApi = "http://localhost:30028/api/values&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(appGetApi, function (_returnedJson) {
       ...
    });
```

But I still get an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) 
http://localhost:30028/api/values&callback=jQuery11020629610788077116_1373178114158?_=1373178114159
```

This is my first time with API and I am completely clueless right now on how to solve this issue. Please help me guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS in W2K3 and above won't serve files that aren't of a MIME type that it knows about (instead returning 404 errors).

You need to add a MIME type to IIS to allow it to serve that type of file. You can set it at the site level or at the server level.

To set this for the entire server:

Open the properties for the server in IIS Manager and click MIME Types
Click "New". Enter "JSON" for the extension and "application/json" for the MIME type.